# FLUTTER: Localization of a multi-screen app

Tags: android, flutter, localization, intl, flutter-intl

i'm creating a multi screen app on android using Flutter.
I'm using intl to localize it, but i don't understand how to procede to create the arb file. Should i run the following commaand
 `flutter pub pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib\l10n lib\main.dart` 
command for every "page/activity/fragment" of my app?

Comment: In addition to "int", I recommend "attranslate" for a semi-automated synchronization of ARB or JSON-files: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate  Otherwise, it could become very tedious to synchronize ARB files manually.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to implement in-app localization? i.e. just changing the app's locale without it being affected by the phone's locale? Then you can refer to this blog: https://blog.geekyants.com/flutter-in-app-localization-438289682f0c

The result would look something like this:

[image: In-App Localization]

Answer (score 1):

To extract [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) messages via [intl_translation](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_translation) into .arb file, you just need to call once `extract_to_arb` command with the relative paths of the files that contain those messages.

```dart
pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=target/directory my_program.dart more_of_my_program.dart
```

Once you translate your extracted messages, you will need to generate .dart localization files via `generate_from_arb` command.

Quickly, you will notice that that becomes tedious, so a better solution would be to use [Flutter Intl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl) extension for VS Code or [Flutter Intl](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) plugin for Android Studio. Using them, you will only need to update your localization files (.arb files), and boilerplate code will be automatically generated.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Start by generating the strings files:
1. Extract all messages to arb file format, which is the template for translations (you can specify multiple files as input.

```
> flutter pub pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n lib/first_file.dart lib/second_file.dart
```

2. Generate translation files in arb format for each language in the form intl_messages_.arb
3. Generate .dart files for the translations (specify one output for each translation):

   > flutter pub pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n \ --no-use-deferred-loading lib/first_file.dart lib/second_file.dart lib/l10n/intl_messages_en.arb lib/l10n/intl_messages_.arb